# XAResource recovery information not serializable

Tags: db2, websphere, xa

We are seeing the following exception in the application while running a UI workflow and it prevents the user from performing the task. So far not able to find the root cause of this error but workaround we use in prod is to bounce the JVM and problem goes away.

The first time incident was reported -
Since the "not serializable" exception occurred while executing the SELECT COUNT SQL from the ibatis mapper class, we made the ibatis object(AlertInboxExample) to implement serializable. This same object (AlertInboxExample) is passed as method argument while invoking the mapper method countByExample(). But that change did not solve the issue and getting this same exception.

```
[1/24/18 23:02:50:404 EST] 00003a85 XATransaction E   J2CA0030E: Method enlist caught javax.transaction.SystemException: XAResource recovery information not serializable
at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.RegisteredResources.enlistResource(RegisteredResources.java:1149)
at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.enlistResource(TransactionImpl.java:2231)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.embeddable.impl.EmbeddableTranManagerSet.enlist(EmbeddableTranManagerSet.java:157)
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.XATransactionWrapper.enlist(XATransactionWrapper.java:733)
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.lazyEnlist(ConnectionManager.java:2697)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.lazyEnlist(WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.java:2606)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.beginTransactionIfNecessary(WSJdbcConnection.java:745)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.prepareStatement(WSJdbcConnection.java:2803)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.prepareStatement(WSJdbcConnection.java:2756)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.instantiateStatement(PreparedStatementHandler.java:50)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.BaseStatementHandler.prepare(BaseStatementHandler.java:64)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.prepare(RoutingStatementHandler.java:39)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.prepareStatement(SimpleExecutor.java:55)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:40)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:243)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:117)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:72)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:79)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:73)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:39)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor406.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:350)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy72.selectOne(Unknown Source)
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectOne(SqlSessionTemplate.java:155)
at com.atom.mybatis.DBSpecificSqlSessionTemplate.selectOne(DBSpecificSqlSessionTemplate.java:106)
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:75)
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:25)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy141.countByExample(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1520.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
at com.atom.mybatis.MapperBeanProxy.invoke(MapperBeanProxy.java:1129)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy141.countByExample(Unknown Source)
at com.atom.alerts.service.impl.AlertInboxServiceImpl.getUnreadAlertCount(AlertInboxServiceImpl.java:105)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1519.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport$1.doInTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager$UOWActionAdapter.run(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:343)
at com.ibm.ws.uow.embeddable.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderCurrentUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:987)
at com.ibm.ws.uow.embeddable.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:374)
at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager.execute(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:287)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy142.getUnreadAlertCount(Unknown Source)
at com.atom.alerts.integration.AlertGroupProducer.getCount(AlertGroupProducer.java:44)
at com.atom.actionitem.BaseActionItemGroupProducer.constructGroupFromFreshData(BaseActionItemGroupProducer.java:203)
at com.atom.actionitem.BaseActionItemGroupProducer.produceActionItemGroup(BaseActionItemGroupProducer.java:130)
at com.atom.actionitem.ActionItemsServiceImpl.retrieveActionItems(ActionItemsServiceImpl.java:66)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1518.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport$1.doInTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager$UOWActionAdapter.run(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:343)
at com.ibm.ws.uow.embeddable.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderNewUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:791)
at com.ibm.ws.uow.embeddable.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:370)
at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager.execute(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:287)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy180.retrieveActionItems(Unknown Source)
at com.atom.dashboard.controllers.ActionItemsController.getActionItems(ActionItemsController.java:37)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1517.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.serviceProxied(ServletWrapper.java:307)
at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleFragment(CacheHook.java:562)
at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleServlet(CacheHook.java:255)
at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:259)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
at com.atom.common.ui.filters.CommonFilterBase.doFilter(CommonFilterBase.java:112)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.atom.common.ui.filters.CommonFilterBase.doFilter(CommonFilterBase.java:112)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.atom.spring.security.filters.SpringCachedPrincipalFilter.doFilter(SpringCachedPrincipalFilter.java:71)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at com.atom.spring.security.filters.SpringConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(SpringConcurrentSessionFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.atom.ui.filters.SystemContextFilter.doFilterBody(SystemContextFilter.java:172)
at com.atom.ui.filters.SystemContextFilter.doFilter(SystemContextFilter.java:135)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.atom.ui.filters.SetAffiliateFilter.doFilter(SetAffiliateFilter.java:217)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.atom.common.ui.filters.CommonFilterBase.doFilter(CommonFilterBase.java:112)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.atom.ui.filters.ExceptionHandlerFilter.doFilter(ExceptionHandlerFilter.java:45)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.atom.conversation.ConversationFilter.doFilter(ConversationFilter.java:84)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88)
at com.atom.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:44)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.atom.ui.util.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:43)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:964)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1104)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1818)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1865)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: XAResource recovery information not serializable
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.PartnerLogData.logRecoveryEntry(PartnerLogData.java:160)
at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.RegisteredResources.enlistResource(RegisteredResources.java:1138)
... 187 more
 while trying to enlist resources from DataSource jdbc/ATDatabaseXA with the Transaction Manager for the current transaction, and threw a ResourceException.
```

**I have struggled to understand how this XA recovery flow works. Need your help to understand this exception and approach to find this non-serialized object.**

Thank you!

Comment: what version of WAS are you running?  I've never seen a case where a user can put anything onto a connection/datasource that needs to be serializable.  It's likely that you will need to open a PMR with IBM and provide some trace logs.

Comment: Name  : IBM WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment
Version: 8.5.5.4

Comment: Thanks Andy. My understanding is, the participating object in XA transaction should be serializable so that it can be deserialized and used during recovery process after a failure event. But then why it works perfectly after server restart and why not fail consistently with same reason is something I don't understand.  Yes, planning to open PMR in case I don't find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of that the user (application or ibatis or spring in this case) might be able to break serialization for XA recovery would be by switching the class loader that is on the thread such that it is not possible to load WebSphere Application Server classes.  The transaction manager does pre-emptive deserialization to ensure that the XA recovery info can be deserialized at a later point.  Changing the class loader could break that, so I'd first check if there is anywhere that the application or ibatis or spring code (if you know) could be switching the class loader.  Otherwise, it seems like a bug in the application server and you should open a PMR as Andy recommended.

Comment: Thank you njr. I don't see the switching of Class Loader during execution. I will take this up as PMR with IBM